# Wilcoxon tests as linear models in R

Tags: r, glm, pairwise.wilcox.test

I found some suggestions throughout the web that suggest that most common statistical tests can be performed using general(ized) linear models (cf. [here](https://lindeloev.github.io/tests-as-linear/#51_independent_t-test_and_mann-whitney_u)). The author suggests to first transform the data into signed ranks (as the wilcoxon test does) and then perform a linear model:

```
signed_rank = function(x) sign(x) * rank(abs(x))

# one-sample test
summary(lm(signed_rank(y) ~ 1))

# two-sample test
summary(lm(signed_rank(z - y) ~ 1)
```

However, due to this rank transformation, the residuals of the linear models are then of course no longer normal. Thus, this general assumption of linear models is not fulfilled. Thus, I wonder whether you can suggest an GLM (generalized linear model) alternative. How would the code look like in R?

Thank a lot for your help in advance!

Comment: It's not clear what your goal is here. I don't think anyone was claiming that the signed ranks would satisfy the assumptions of linear models, just that a linear model on signed ranks was **approximately equivalent** to a Wilcoxon test.

Comment: @BenBolker Yeah, maybe. But the p value "estimation" can be quite biased then. To make the approximation of multiple tests by linear models, one has to find a way to estimate p values correctly, right? Otherwise it doesn't make sense to use such a test at all (in terms of hypotheses testing). Thus, I wonder whether a GLM (e.g. assuming a beta link function could be applied here). Of course, then the original data would need ot be adjusted to a range of [0, 1]. (?!) Could that be a valid procedure (from hypotheses point of view) and what would be the R formula to apply such a GLM?

Comment: Seems like a stretch/might be a better question for [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) ... (wouldn't solve the "what's the R code for this?" question but would address the more fundamental "is there a sensible way to formulate this?" question ...)